# UIWebView producing about:blank requests when iframe appended

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

This simple code

`var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);`

injected by `UIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString`
produces invocation of `UIWebViewDelegate shouldStartLoadWithRequest` with `about:blank`. Which interestingly still has `mainDocumentURL` set to the document that was there at the time of injection. For me it means that i can't inject such code whenever i want - reentry to `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` observably breaks a lot of things. I can reject all `about:blank` requests (returning `NO` from `shouldStart...`) and code snippets from the internets do it cluelessly, but it's hardly a systematic solution.

Any ideas why `UIWebView` has this confusing and useless behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you don't set a `src` attribute on your `iframe`, it will load `about:blank` by default. If you want to avoid this behavior you could set a dummy value using `iframe.setAttribute` before you add the `iframe` to the document and then cancel the dummy request in `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`.

Comment: Ok so it's not confusing and can be even instrumented to be useful. Somewhat embarrassing :-)